# Hide a column in GridView doesn't work in EF6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, gridview, presentation-layer

i create a model using EF6 . I want to invisible my column in **Gridview window form** using this code :

```
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

I used both of `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` and `[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]`.but it doesn't work and the column `Date` is shown again in **gridview**.

why ?

Best regards

Comment: I am using windows form

Comment: Entity Framework is a persistence layer and has not the least in common with a GridView from WinForms. Please decide whether you want to ask a EF or a WinForms question and narrow it down accordingly.

Comment: You mean EF and WinForm are separate subjects?

Comment: Just hide it in datagridview. Mark datagridviewcolumn as `Visible = false`